# Save and restore a variable across launches

Tags: vimrc, variables

I wanna save the state of a variable (say, `background`) such that the state is restored next time I start vim.

More in detail, it should work like this:

1. I set `background` to either dark or light.
2. I open a new instance of VIM. (I may or may not have quit out of the old instance first)
3. On startup of the new instance, `background` is automatically set to the value set in 1.

I could probably hand-code a command that sets the variable, writes its value to some file, and have the file read on startup. But perhaps there's an easier way to get what I want?

Comment: `:help viminfo-!`

Comment: @Matt ah nice, this is prob gonna do it! I saw I can also write this manually via `:wv`, so I can save the setting for instances starting in parallel. Thx!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Make sure to add an answer if you solve your problem!